# JMeter Plugin for count how many request fail and pass

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter have any plugin or option  for counting total pass and fail request and  give summary wise  count  and also how  to find response time for every request

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thread Group -> Add -> Listener -> Summary Report

That should meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Which format?

0. JMeter's [summarizer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode/) outputs basic stats for the samplers when you run your test in non-GUI mode:

   [image]
1. JMeter's [.jtl files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) are basically CSV files so you can import them into [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/excel.aspx) and there you will have response times for all requests and the information regarding whether they're successful or not
2. There is an option to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) which gives you statistics on passed/failed requests
3. You can open the aforementioned .jtl results file using [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) which contains statistical information on all the results or [View Results in Table](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table)
4. You can generate the CSV output of the Aggregate Report/Summary Report listeners via [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)